# Is it safe to clone Tails to a used USB?

Tags: usb, firmware

If one has a USB stick, originally from a trusted source and without hacked firmware, but one has used this USB stick with an unsafe system, then can it safely be plugged it into a Tails OS system and be overwritten by cloning Tails onto it?

By "safe", I mean that the system does not get physically comprimised (e.g. altered firmware) and the Tails OS is not modified.

If it's not safe, then what would a potential attack vector be?

### Further Explanation

Of course one could just throw out the USB stick and buy a new one.

But a variation on this question would be plugging in the used USB in order to copy non-executable files from the unsafe system, and then asking if this is a safe way to transfer files?

Comment: Safe from what? What bad thing do you not want to happen?

Comment: What kind of USB device are you speaking about?

Comment: Instead of cloning USB storage, you could simply dowload image from official site, then burn your owjn device with this image (after checking them).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: OP, are you asking: Can the USB drive that contains the unsafe system possibly compromise the Tails instance on the system that the USB drive is connected to - and If so then, when Tails clones itself to the USB drive, could the Tails instance on the USB drive also be compromised as well?

Comment: Edited, to hopefully address the questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not unconditionally safe.

*If* the USB stick is vulnerable to [BadUSB](https://www.itsb.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/themen/badusb.html) type attacks, and *if* the "unsafe" system it has been used with was compromised to perform that kind of attack on connected USB sticks, then the firmware of the stick could be compromised to perform USB-based attacks on any systems it may be connected to in the future.
This kind of compromise will **not** be removed by just overwriting the data on the stick, for example with a Tails image.

So after cloning Tails onto it, such a stick would still (try to) attack any system it is plugged into. To begin with, it may compromise the very system you use to do the cloning. It may also attack the installed OS of systems you intend to boot Tails on, if you plug it in while the installed OS is running. And it may even try to attack the Tails image as soon as you boot it from the stick. (Although Tails is certainly not the easiest of targets.)

Whether any of these attacks will actually succeed is a different question. But they are theoretically possible.

Comment: Imho BadUSB was overhyped by the media and not a lot of controllers in the flash drives are vulnerable to it.

Comment: Definitely. Hence my two emphasized ifs. But it is theoretically possible, so the absolute question "is it safe" must be answered: "No, not absolutely."

Comment: OK, so just inserting a USB stick into a compromised system could possibly turn it into a BadUSB, for example? I ask, because the one tutorial I found online on creating a BadUSB involved opening up the USB stick and shorting two pins.

Comment: Just inserting a _vulnerable_ USB stick could do that, yes. The BadUSB PoC published by Adam Caudill und Brandon Wilson in 2014 worked against unmodified sticks with a certain type of controller. One would hope that controller manufacturers have since elliminated that kind of vulnerability, so as @SirMuffington wrote, sticks vulnerable to BadUSB should be rare.

Comment: I understand now, as far as BadUSB goes. But it is still possible that there are newer BadUSB variants that could comprimise the USB firmware even on a newer stick? Or are you saying that it is possible to eliminate this type of attack completely with a properly manufactured controller?

Comment: Not "or", but "and". A properly manufactured controller should of course not present that kind of vulnerability, but it is possible that newer sticks still come with controllers that are not properly manufactured in this sense, especially given the enormous price pressure on those products which gives manufacturers a strong incentive to cut corners.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt now I may not be an USB expert, but umm I think you're kind of technically wrong. BadUSB showed rather a general flaw in USB, which is that the controller is *NOT* a fixed purpose controller without the ability to change functionality that easily. In other words, a simple controller saying it's a mass storage media can be easily reprogrammed to be a multimedia keyboard. I see that as an inherent weakness in USB. Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The USB mass storage standard does not specify a mechanism to reprogram the controller. If such a mechanism exists it's either a bug or an incredibly stupid proprietary extension. Anyway, it's the manufacturer's responsibility, not a general flaw in USB.